# FormView Manual Data binding

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a FormView that I user for updating a record. There is a link button that when fires should perforom the updating via BLL and DAL. I am not using built-in ODS and I will not condsider using it.

I have all my grids and formviews populated manuualy by calling methods that fetch the data from the database.

For instance my details view is populated like this:

```
protected void DlMembers_ItemCommand(object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName.ToString() == "Select")
    {
        DlMembers.Visible = false;
        lblError.Text = string.Empty;
        lblError.Visible = false;
        fvMemberDetail.Visible = true;
        fvMemberDetail.ChangeMode(FormViewMode.Edit);

        MemberBLL getMemberInfo = new MemberBLL();

        int Ident = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument.ToString());

        fvMemberDetail.DataSource = getMemberInfo.GetMemberByIdent(Ident);
        fvMemberDetail.DataBind();

    }

    if (e.CommandName.ToString() == "DeleteSelected")
    {
        DlMembers.Visible = true;
        lblError.Text = string.Empty;
        lblError.Visible = false;
        fvMemberDetail.Visible = false;
        fvMemberDetail.ChangeMode(FormViewMode.ReadOnly);
  }
```

What I want to do if to capature my linkbutton on click event and do this (except that the runtime never reaches this method):

```
protected void MemberInfoUpdating(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox id = (TextBox)fvMemberDetail.FindControl("txtIdent");

    if (id.Text != string.Empty || id.Text != "")
    {
        TextBox txtFN = (TextBox)fvMemberDetail.FindControl("txtFN");
        TextBox txtLN = (TextBox)fvMemberDetail.FindControl("txtLN");
        DropDownList ddlAddress = (DropDownList)fvMemberDetail.FindControl("ddlAddress");
        TextBox txtEmail = (TextBox)fvMemberDetail.FindControl("txtEmail");
        TextBox txtHPhone = (TextBox)fvMemberDetail.FindControl("txtHPhone");
        TextBox txtWPhone = (TextBox)fvMemberDetail.FindControl("txtWPhone");
        TextBox txtMPhone = (TextBox)fvMemberDetail.FindControl("txtMPhone");
        DropDownList ddlPos = (DropDownList)fvMemberDetail.FindControl("ddlPos");
        DropDownList ddlIsAdmin = (DropDownList)fvMemberDetail.FindControl("ddlIsAdmin");
        bool blIsAdmin = false;
        if (ddlIsAdmin.SelectedValue == "True") blIsAdmin = true;
        TextBox txtComments = (TextBox)fvMemberDetail.FindControl("txtComments");

        MemberBLL updateMemberInfo = new MemberBLL();

        bool UpdateOK = updateMemberInfo.UpdateMemberByIdent(
                        txtFN.Text,
                        txtLN.Text,
                        ddlAddress.SelectedValue,
                        txtEmail.Text,
                        txtHPhone.Text,
                        txtWPhone.Text,
                        txtMPhone.Text,
                        blIsAdmin,
                        txtComments.Text,
                        Convert.ToInt32(ddlPos.SelectedValue),
                        Convert.ToInt32(id.Text));
    }
    else
    {
        //Display error - no user id cannot update record
    }
}
```

The linkbutton looks like this:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="UpdateButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" 
                OnClick="MemberInfoUpdating" Text="Update" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where is this LinkButton?  If it's inside a FormView template, then you'll likely need to use something like this instead:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="UpdateButton" runat="server" CommandName="Update" Text="Update" />
```

Then handle the "Update" command in DlMembers_ItemCommand.

Alternatively, attach your code to the OnItemUpdating event of the FormView rather than some extra event you don't need:

```
<asp:FormView ID="fvMemberDetail" runat="server" OnItemUpdating="MemberInfoUpdating">
```

Comment: <asp:DataList Width="700" ID="DlMembers" runat="server" DataKeyField="Ident" OnItemCommand="DlMembers_ItemCommand" OnDeleteCommand="DlMembers_DeleteCommand" ><asp:LinkButton ID="lbEdit" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Select" Text="Edit"                             CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Ident") %>' />            </EditItemTemplate>

Comment: Hmmmm... afraid I'm at a loss then.  I can tell you, however, that the most common cause of non-firing events in my experience is that databound controls are being incorrectly bound -- either rebound when they should not be, or bound in the wrong page lifecycle event.